# Facebook login returning null for name result

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, sdk

I am trying to use the new Facebook 4.0 sdks, but I was quite confused about how to get the name once I successfully get the permissions. The nslog returns a null value for some reason?

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // Process error           

        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            // Handle cancellations

        } else {
        //success

            _nam = [FBSDKProfile currentProfile].name;
            NSLog(@"name %@", _nam);

     }}];
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and check what [FBSDKProfile currentProfile] is at that time using lldb

Comment: It was returned null as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292371/facebook-sdk-v4-0-for-ios-fbsdkprofile-currentprofile-not-being-set looks like that is your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up solving it.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // Process error           

        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            // Handle cancellations

        } else {
   [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (error) {

             }
             else {
                 NSString *userID = [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] userID];
                 NSString *userName = [result valueForKey:@"name"];
}}];
}}];
```