# FBSDKProfile currentProfile is nil but FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken has value

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Just like what the title says, is this a bug or is it really possible? I use the `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString` to check whether an existing Facebook session is existing, then afterwards I'll use the `[FBSDKProfile currentProfile].userID` to get the session's userId. 
However sometimes I encounter that `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString` has a value but `[FBSDKProfile currentProfile]` is nil.

I use this for the auto-login feature of my application.

Thanks for your response!

So I have this code snippet:

```
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString){
//proceed to auto login since Facebook is still logged in
        NSLog(@"Facebook user id: %@",[FBSDKProfile currentProfile].userID)
    }
```

The return of that log is nil.

Comment: Please provide the appopriate code snippets for the error which you are seeing, in order for people to better understand and answer you question

Comment: I've edited my post. Thanks! I hope the information provided is enough. I just want to clarify if it is possible to have an existing token, but the Facebook profile is nil.

Comment: The code is not sufficient, it would be more helpful to have a complete sample project here. Have you checked that the token is actually valid once you end up in the above described situation where you have a token but FBSDKProfile is nil?

Comment: There's no checking whether the current token is valid. The solution I've made is not to rely on FBSDKProfile, but rather I'm just using the [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].userID instead of [FBSDKProfile currentProfile].userID as [FBSDKProfile currentProfile] becomes nil.

Comment: "The FBSDKProfile fetch may not have been completed by the time of the login callback. Instead you can observe for a 'FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification' notification post."
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292371/facebook-sdk-v4-0-for-ios-fbsdkprofile-currentprofile-not-being-set

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString) {
    [FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];
    NSLog(@"Facebook user id: %@",[FBSDKProfile currentProfile].userID);
}
```

you need to call `[FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES]` so that it automatically observes changes to the `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]`

Comment: also you can use this to get image
[[FBSDKProfile currentProfile] imageURLForPictureMode:FBSDKProfilePictureModeNormal size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)]

Answer (score 1):

You may need to load the current profile, use this following snippet, after the callback runs you will get the profile data unless you don't have current token.
[image]